# How to check if a Cesium Entity is visible / occluded

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

Given an Entity, I'm trying to figure out if at a particular moment/frame, if one of the entities is viewable on the screen.

The closest I could find was Entity.isVisible, but it seems to just tally the explicit `show` properties. It returns true even if...

- Transparency is 0%
- The Entity is out of frame (eg. above the viewable area)
- The Entity is occluded (eg. on the other side of the Earth)

I also can't find any functions to convert the entity position to viewport coordinates to test if it is at least within the camera view cone.

I had one idea to measure the distance between the entity and the camera kinda like this `Cesium.Cartesian3.distance(this.viewer.selectedEntity.position.getValue(Cesium.JulianDate.now()), this.viewer.camera.position);` But obviously the acceptable distance needs to be based on the camera height, FOV and if the camera is even looking in that direction. I haven't yet been able to get the math to work for this solution.

How can I tell if an Entity is currently visible to the user?

Answer (score 4):

One of the ways is to use [BoundingSphere](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/BoundingSphere.html) in the frustum culling. Then check if the bounding sphere of the entity is visible in the culling volume.

```js
const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
const camera = viewer.camera;

const position = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(23.9036, 54.8985);

const frustum = camera.frustum;
const cullingVolume = frustum.computeCullingVolume(
  camera.position,
  camera.direction,
  camera.up
);

const someEntity = viewer.entities.add({
    name: 'Some Point',
    position: position,
    point: {
        pixelSize: 14,
        color: Cesium.Color.GREEN
    }
});

// Bounding sphere of the entity.
let boundingSphere = new Cesium.BoundingSphere();
viewer.dataSourceDisplay.getBoundingSphere(someEntity, false, boundingSphere);

// Check if the entity is visible in the screen.
const intersection = cullingVolume.computeVisibility(boundingSphere);

console.log(intersection);
//  1: Cesium.Intersect.INSIDE
//  0: Cesium.Intersect.INTERSECTING
// -1: Cesium.Intersect.OUTSIDE
```

I have also made a [Cesium Sandcastle example](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/index.html#c=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).